# How to display all errors for a form with nested forms

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

How can I show ALL error messages of a form with nested forms from Symfony 2.8 in Twig?
I dont mean a single error message for a single specific field - 
I mean something like this:
(This is from the official docu of symfony - but it is not work - I think it is not working because I have nested forms)

```
{% block form_errors %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

This is how I build the form:

```
/**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
            ->add(
                'text',
                new OtherType(OtherType::class),
                array(
                    'label'              => 'page.richtext.text',
                    'translation_domain' => 'entities',
                    'required'           => false,
                )
            );
    }
```

Is there some method or function that I can use for display all error messages from a symfony formType that includes other nested formTypes - ?

Comment: Does your otherType has the option `error_bubbling` enabled?

Comment: not until now - I try this: ... array(
                    'error_bubbling'     => true,
                    'label'              => 'page.richtext.text',
                    'translation_domain' => 'entities',
                    'required'           => false,
                )

but this also does not work.

Comment: @veve - YES - you safe my day! This option -> 'error_bubbling'     => true, has to be placed in my child formType - this work. Please write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: glad it helped you, answer added ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add and set the [`error_bubbling` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#error-bubbling) to `true` in your children formType to get the errors in your parent form.

Answer (score 1):

In your twig file of this form add this line fordisplaying error:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

Comment: no this does not work. This will only show the error messages under the specific field - but I try to display ALL error messages from my form with all the nested forms with a loop.

Comment: Your answer is partially right - my problem was the error_bubling = true -> because of children formType elements.